# Why does HtmlElement's GetAttribute() method return "mshtml.HTMLInputElementClass" instead of the attribute's value?

Tags: c#, browser

Why does `HtmlElement`'s `GetAttribute()` method return `mshtml.HTMLInputElementClass` instead of the attribute's value, when I'm trying to obtain the value of a form's `action` attribute?

```
HtmlElementCollection elements = webBrowser1.Document.Forms;
   foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
        MessageBox.Show(element.GetAttribute("action") + "");
```

Comment: No repro.  Post the HTML that shows the form.

Comment: Sample that works: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

Comment: http://amazines.com/member_login.cfm

Comment: It appears that the form's action leads to a https page. Should this be the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an IE bug.

Here is a solution : **add a reference to Microsoft.mshtml**, then :

```
if(element.GetAttribute("action").Equals("mshtml.HTMLInputElementClass"))
{
    mshtml.IHTMLFormElement iForm = (mshtml.IHTMLFormElement)element.DomElement; 
    string action = iForm.action;
}
```

Hope this help :)