# System.__ComObject is returned when I use getAttribute

Tags: c#, winforms

I am running this code:

```
HtmlElement.GetAttribute("onClick")
```

To try and get access to the onClick attribute of that element, but all this returns is System.__ComObject. I don't know why this happens, all other GetAttribute calls return the actual string.

Thanks.

Comment: try next post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223840/how-to-get-actual-javascript-value-in-onclick-from-webbrowser-control

Comment: I already saw that, there was no clear answer.

Comment: That's because onClick is an event, not a string.  Consider using HtmlElement.Click instead, it isn't otherwise clear what you want to do with onClick.

Comment: When an element has "onClick = "blabla" "

I want to get "blabla".

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try to determine type of the control; then cast your object to this type. Accessing properties of element is possible with this method.

For example, if your object is a "div" contains an "onclick" method, you must convert your com object to `mshtml.HTMLDivElement` (You must add assembly "mshtml.dll" into your project for using mshtml class); then you can look for "onclick" attribute in `outerHTML` property.

```
    if (doc.GetElementById("id-of-div").GetAttribute("onclick").Equals("System.__ComObject"))
    {
            mshtml.HTMLDivElement docCOM = (mshtml.HTMLDivElement)doc.GetElementById("id-of-div").DomElement;

            string onClickStr = docCOM.outerHTML.[some string or regex operations here];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Sample code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707869/system-comobject-is-returned-when-i-use-getattribute")
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Dim a As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("portalLink").FirstChild
    MsgBox(a.DomElement.attributes("onclick").value.ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use this code:

```
theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")

For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
    MsgBox(curElement.DomElement.attributes("onclick").value.ToString)
Next
```