# How getAttribute("onclick")

Tags: c#, onclick, webbrowser-control, getattribute

For example I have this html code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return Index.submit_login('server_pl80');">
    <span class="world_button_active">Świat 80</span>
</a>
```

And I need to get attribute of onclick, because I may get more links and I must find difference between them. For my opinion get attribute of onclick is only one way.
But if I GetAttribute("onclick") from HTMLElement it will return System.__ComObject.

Is there any idea how read onclick value from webBrowser?

Comment: Can you show the code you use to query the DOM?

Comment: use `onClick` instead of `onclick`

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [System.__ComObject is returned when I use getAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707869/system-comobject-is-returned-when-i-use-getattribute). Use `attributes("onclick").value.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only this:

```
HtmlElement selected_div = @webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("div_id").GetElementsByTagName("div")[0];
HtmlElement a = selected_div.GetElementsByTagName("a")[0];

string rightLink = a.GetAttribute("href");
string onclickLink = a.GetAttribute("onclick"); // return "System.__ComObject" string

if (rightLink == "http://www.example.com/#")
     a.InvokeMember("click", null);
```

"onclick" or "onClick" in getAttribute(); doesn't make a difference

This code works but click on first link on the list of servers.. I need choose the server and links have difference only in onclick attribute.